# Using JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialise a derived List

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a simple class:

```
 public class ProductListStoredModel: List<Product>
 {
        public int NextId { get; set; }
 }
```

If I use:

```
  ProductListStoredModel stored_model = ...
  string new_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stored_model);
```

It will happily serialise the list. However, it doesn't add 'NextId' to the JSON. Is there a simple way to do that (like adding an attribute)?

Comment: share the class name or library name that you are using for json serializing.

Comment: It's the one that comes with VS2013: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

Comment: The `Newtonsoft.Json` does not support this so you need to write a custom converter.But in your opinion how should the generated JSON response look like in this case? I would change my class to `public class ProductListStoredModel
 {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public int NextId { get; set; }
 }`...

Comment: The reason it is like that is because it comes into an MVC3 controller as a JSON object. I think the moral of the tale is: don't let your internal model get dictated from one outside - convert as required ... or more specifically in my case: don't be so darned lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ProductListStoredModel stored_model = new ProductListStoredModel();
            Product p = new Product();
            stored_model.Add(p);
            stored_model.NextId = 10;
            stored_model.Pro = stored_model[0];
            string new_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stored_model);
            Console.WriteLine(new_json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class ProductListStoredModel : List<Product>
    {
        //public Product[] pro { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public int NextId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public Product Pro { get; set; }

    }
```

you can make an array property of product as well and can continue so on.

```
public Product[] Pro { get; set; }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to serialise the list when it inherits (as above). I found that if I aggregated the list and removed all the attributes it works.